# navigate to next tab post clicking on link

Tags: shiny

Below is the application. I need to navigate to next tab when clicked on "I clicked" on DT table. But as per below code, that is not working. Can anyone help me........................................................................

```
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)
library(DT)

# UI ---------------------------------------------------------------------

ui <- fluidPage(
  tabsetPanel(
    id = "panels",
    tabPanel(
      "A",
      p(),
      DTOutput("tab")
      # actionLink("link_to_tabpanel_b", "Link to panel B")
      # HTML('<a id="Iclickehase" class="action-button" href="#">I clicked</a>')
    ),
    tabPanel(
      "B",
      h3("Some information"),
      tags$li("Item 1"),
      tags$li("Item 2"),
      actionLink("link_to_tabpanel_a", "Link to panel A")
    )
  )
)

# Server ------------------------------------------------------------------

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  #   observeEvent(input$link_to_tabpanel_b, {
  #     tags$a(href = "#tab-4527-2")
  #   })
  
  df <- data.frame(a = c(1))
  df$b <- HTML('<a id="Iclickehase" class="action-button" href="#">I clicked</a>')
  # 
  output$tab <- renderDataTable({
    datatable(df,escape = F,selection = 'none')
  })
  
  observeEvent(input$Iclickehase, {
    newvalue <- "B"
    updateTabItems(session, "panels", newvalue)
  })
  observeEvent(input$link_to_tabpanel_a, {
    newvalue <- "A"
    updateTabsetPanel(session, "panels", newvalue)
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When adding inputs (like the actionLink) to a datatable you need to bind them manually, [here](https://community.rstudio.com/t/what-is-the-purpose-of-using-shiny-bindall/14489/2) is why.

Please check the following:

```
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)
library(DT)

# UI ---------------------------------------------------------------------

ui <- fluidPage(tabsetPanel(
  id = "panels",
  tabPanel("A",
           p(),
           DTOutput("tab")),
  tabPanel("B",
    h3("Some information"),
    tags$li("Item 1"),
    tags$li("Item 2"),
    actionLink("link_to_tabpanel_a", "Link to panel A")
  )
))

# Server ------------------------------------------------------------------

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  
  DF <- data.frame(a = c(1))
  DF$b <- HTML('<a id="Iclickehase" class="action-button" href="#">I clicked</a>')
  
  output$tab <- renderDataTable({
    datatable(
      DF,
      escape = FALSE,
      selection = 'none',
      options = list(
        preDrawCallback = JS('function() { Shiny.unbindAll(this.api().table().node()); }'),
        drawCallback = JS('function() { Shiny.bindAll(this.api().table().node()); } ')
      )
    )
  })
  
  observeEvent(input$Iclickehase, {
    newvalue <- "B"
    updateTabItems(session, "panels", newvalue)
  })
  observeEvent(input$link_to_tabpanel_a, {
    newvalue <- "A"
    updateTabsetPanel(session, "panels", newvalue)
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. But if the table value changes due to filtering, then this navigation will not happen? Why so? Can we solve this?

Comment: The binding might get lost after re-rendering the table. However, in your above example no filtering is done. Please post a new question with an appropriate example to track down the issue.

Comment: I added another question here. Can you please help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70006107/is-there-a-way-to-make-links-work-when-data-is-filtered